# How do i retrieve multiple documents from cloud firestore, but no duplicates?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to randomly pull a documents from a list of document. And currently, it works, but I will receive the same document again, but I don't want to.

```
let qnumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
const dialogflowAgentDoc = db.collection('esequiz').doc(''+qnumber);
```

So how do I edit it such that I do not pull any duplicates from the random document pulled?

So my cloud firestore looks like this, hence I use qnumber to determine a random number made up, and then called into db collection.

[image]]

Comment: Please provide primary data in js format and desirable result

Comment: I am unaware of the primary data in js format, as for the database i just create it inside of firebase, cloud firestore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to track IDs of retrieved documents and discard random IDs that were already retrieved.

Pseudo code:

```
class UniqueRandomIdProvider()
{
   alreadyRetrieved: number[] = [];

   public getNewRandomId(): number {
     while(true) {
     {
        const randomId = this.getRandomId();
        if (!this.alreadyRetrieved.contains(randomId) {
            return randomId;
        }   
     }

   }

   private getRandomId(): number {
      return Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand how to convert this into javascript language, since javascript is used in fulfillment dialogflow

Comment: the document id is literally the numbers in the picture shown, left column